# Catching IOException

Tags: c#, file-io, io, inputstream

I am writing a C# application in which I have to display a message if File is already being used by some process and if the file doesnot exist, the application needs to display another message.

Something like this:

```
try 
{
    //Code to open a file
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e IS IOException)
    {
        //if File is being used by another process
        MessageBox.Show("Another user is already using this file.");

        //if File doesnot exist
        MessageBox.Show("Documents older than 90 days are not allowed.");
    }
}
```

Since `IOException` covers both the conditions, how do I distinguish if this exception is caught because of File being used by another process or File doesnot exist?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's *just* throwing `IOException` in both cases? Not [`FileNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception) for example? (And why are you catching `Exception` and then using `is` rather than catching `IOException` in a separate catch block?)

Comment: You know you can use catch like this: `catch(IOException ioe){//handle ie exception}catch(Exception e){//handle unknown exception}`

Comment: FileNotFoundException will be thrown when the file doesn't exist. More info here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ioexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.file.openread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) File.OpenRead can throw these exception type

1. [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [PathTooLongException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
4. [DirectoryNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
5. [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
6. [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx)
7. [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.notsupportedexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

for each of this exception type you can handle it in this way

```
try{

}
catch(ArgumentException e){
  MessageBox.Show("ArgumentException ");
}
catch(ArgumentNullExceptione e){
 MessageBox.Show("ArgumentNullExceptione");
}
.
.
.
.        
catch(Exceptione e){
     MessageBox.Show("Generic");
}
```

In your case you can handle just one or two types and other are always catched by generic `Exception` (it must be always the lastone because cathces all Exceptions)

Comment: So, 7 exception handlers in one method? I think not.

Comment: It is a generic way to show how you can handle your exceptions. If you need only two you catch that 2 types and the generic Exception

Comment: @Polyfun There is nothing wrong with acting upon different exception types, what if you want to act upon each of them differently?

Answer (score 3):

Always catch from the most specific to the most generic exception type.
Every exception inherits the `Exception`-class, thus you will catch **any exception** in your `catch (Exception)` statement.

This will filter IOExceptions and every else separately:

```
catch (IOException ioEx)
{
     HandleIOException(ioEx);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     HandleGenericException(ex);
}
```

So catch `Exception` always last. Checking with if is possible, but not common.

About your problem:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) // File still exists, so obviously blocked by another process
```

This would be the simplest solution to separate your conditions.

Comment: checking File.Exists() can make more sense. If the file not being found is an expected situation logically, then check for it rather than 'expected excpetion'. And unless you really have something global to do for all excpetion like showing an error page in a website or log errors, don't catch 'Exception', that's a real bad habit. Consider 'OutOfMemoryException' that can always happen just from executing the code, this one should bubble up and letting the application crash, perhaps after trying to log, can be a sensible way to handle it.

Comment: @SharpShade That's exactly what I did. Except for the fact that I didn't check if the file existed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
try
{
  //open file
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Documents older than 90 days are not allowed.");
}
catch (IOException)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Another user is already using this file.");
}
```

More info: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ioexception

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the only consistent solution to do this is to filter catch blocks by the HResult property. I don't know which one it is but here's an example for copying a file and catching if the file already exists :

```
        try
        {
            File.Copy(source, dest, false); // Try to copy the file normally
        }
        catch (IOException e) when (e.HResult == -2147024816) // 0x80070050 : The file already exists
        {
             // Prompt user for overwrite...
        }
```

Consult the .NET reference source and track the Win32 calls to find the returned HResult.

Answer (score -1):

When file not exists it will throw the FileNotFoundException that inherit IOException, So you can write like this:

> ```
> try 
> {
>     //file operate
> }
> catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
> {
>     MessageBox.Show("Documents older than 90 days are not allowed.");
> }
> catch (IOException ex)
> {
>     MessageBox.Show("Another user is already using this file.");
> }
> ```